# "L" select connected selection tool doesn't work

Tags: selection-tools

In the below scene, I cannot seem to select the shape on the left by hovering over it and pressing "L" select connected.

[image]

In the below screen shot, I pressed L to select other elements of the scene, and all became selected properly:

[image]

But no matter how much I try, I cannot seem to select the left side shape...

Comment: I pressed "L" ten times and it eventually selected it... ?????

Comment: Deselet all by pressing A. Select one vertex with the right mouse buton. Then press L to select other vertices connected to it.

Comment: But usually when everything is deselected (A key), I can just hover over an element and press L. Why would it be different now?

Comment: Small addition to the answer below and comments above: if you already have any componenets (verts, edges, faces) selected, press Ctrl + L to select the entire island.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a cursor proximity **thereshold** in the "Select Linked".

If you are in vertex mode, the cursor must be near a vertex to catch the vertex. It won't work if none of the object's vertices fall into the cursor's radius (e.g. if it is in the middle of a big face)

[image]